# Why always popping up Refreshing error in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, refresh

Im getting below error everytime when im refreshing the dataset in power BI desktop.I have unticked the auto date and time in Options too.In below image shows two tables i have deleted previously from the model.Why the error coming with the deleted tables which stating that tables cannot find? and its stating that theres not enough memory.

[image]

Comment: Check if any steps in your queries reference these tables.

Comment: @Dreekun is right, have a look at the "advanced editor" for each table, somewhere those tables are still referenced, also power query should already tell you if something is not working in a table.